# Días no laborales y feriados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy que hago un pequeño sistema donde envió un mensaje a una persona y este mensaje tiene una cantidad de días en especifico que la persona lo puede responder. **Por ejemplo** sí le envió un mensaje que solo cuente con 10 días, el tiempo de días solo tiene que contar de lunes a viernes menos fin de semanas y feriados. Pedí ayuda a unos amigos y pues me dijeron que cree una tabla donde estén los días que no son laborables incluyendo feriados:

```
CREATE TABLE Feriados(
IdFeriado int primary key identity,
NombreDia varchar(50) null,
Fecha datetime null,
AnioMesDias varchar(10) null
);
```

Datos agregados:

```
IdFeriado   Nombre  Fecha                    AnioMesDias    
1           Sabado  2019-09-07 00:00:00.000  20190907
2           Domingo 2019-09-08 00:00:00.000  20190908
3           Feriado 2019-09-09 00:00:00.000  20190909
```

Entonces...en mi consulta como haría para que calcule la fecha de inicio sumado mas los días de plazo pero que no cuenten los días agregado a la tabla Feriados y que me de resultado de la fecha final.

Comment: Sería recomendable que incluyeras el código que has intentado utilizar para llegar a la solución. Te recomiendo ver: [repro] y [ask].

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta en si, para lo de sabado y domingo no es necesario usar la tabla se puede excluir con una simple consulta

Comment: @EdgarVazques y como haria para excluir los feriados tambien??

Comment: A que te quieres referir con feriados, yo se que feriados son sabado y domingo eso se puede con lo que te digo

Comment: @EdgarVazquez por ejemplo aparte de sabados y domingos, un miercoles es feriado...entonces como haria para excluir ese dia tambien. Y si hay mas dias para excluir? Me dijeron que cree una tabla con los dias que no quiero que cuenten

Comment: Si eso es correcto pero en esa tabla solo tendrias el mes y el dia por un decir que en mexico el 16 de septiembre es feriado entonces en tu tabla metes 09 que es el mes y 16 que es dia

Comment: @EdgarVazquez y como seria eso en codigo? si me podrias apoyar :s

Comment: Claro permiteme te creo el ejemplo

Comment: @EdgarVazquez ok gracias

Comment: Bienvenido @SalazarE! Podrías explicar cuál es tu problema? El problema, no los consejos que te dieron para solucionarlo. A simple vista la solución de @ManuelRobles debería funcionar... pero sospecho que tu problema es más complejo que eso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya se ha mencionado una opción para calcular al vuelo los días hábiles teniendo una tabla de días feriados. Sin embargo, al probar la consulta me regresó valores semi-aleatorios puesto que falta asignar orden. Tampoco tiene opción para fines de semana. Así que aquí dejo mi versión.

```
DECLARE @FechaInicio    DATETIME
DECLARE @Dias       INT

SELECT @FechaInicio = '20190907'
SELECT @Dias        = 10;

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteCalendario(Fecha) AS(
    SELECT  TOP( @Dias + (((@Dias / 365) + 1) * 110)) --Formula para regresar suficientes fechas sin quedarnos cortos
            DATEADD( DD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, @FechaInicio) Fecha
    FROM E4
),
cteDiasHabiles(Fecha) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@Dias) 
            Fecha
    FROM cteCalendario c
    WHERE DATEDIFF( DD, '19000101', Fecha) % 7 NOT IN (5,6) --Sábado y Domingo
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Feriados f WHERE f.Fecha = c.Fecha)
    ORDER BY Fecha
)
SELECT MAX(Fecha) FechaTermino
FROM cteDiasHabiles;
```

Sin embargo, una consulta así es complicada de combinar con algo más grande, a menos de que la convirtamos en una función. Es importante saber que las funciones usualmente afectan el rendimiento de SQL Server, a excepción de las funciones en linea tipo tabla (o tipo escalar en la versión 2019). Afortunadamente, la conversión es sencilla.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FechaTerminoSinDiasInhabiles(
    @FechaInicio    DATETIME,
    @Dias           INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    WITH 
    E(n) AS(
        SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
    ),
    E2(n) AS(
        SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
    ),
    E4(n) AS(
        SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
    ),
    cteCalendario(Fecha) AS(
        SELECT  TOP( @Dias + (((@Dias / 365) + 1) * 110)) --Formula para regresar suficientes fechas sin quedarnos cortos
                DATEADD( DD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, @FechaInicio) Fecha
        FROM E4
    ),
    cteDiasHabiles(Fecha) AS(
        SELECT TOP(@Dias) 
                Fecha
        FROM cteCalendario c
        WHERE DATEDIFF( DD, '19000101', Fecha) % 7 NOT IN (5,6) --Sábado y Domingo
        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Feriados f WHERE f.Fecha = c.Fecha)
        ORDER BY Fecha
    )
    SELECT MAX(Fecha) FechaTermino
    FROM cteDiasHabiles;

GO
```

Y la podemos llamar con la cláusula `APPLY`.

```
SELECT t.ColumnasDeMiTabla,
       t.Fecha AS FechaInicio,
       t.Dias AS DiasHabiles,
       f.FechaTermino,
       t.MasColumnas
FROM dbo.MiTabla t
CROSS APPLY dbo.FechaTerminoSinDiasInhabiles( t.Fecha, t.Dias) f;
```

Personalmente, creo que la verdadera opción tradicional según la teoría de base de datos, es tener una tabla de calendario en la que almacenes todos los atributos que pueda tener una fecha. Dos de esos atributos pueden ser banderas para saber si son feriados o fin de semana (o ambos). Aquí hay una muestra de como construir una con casi 27 años (pero faltaría asignar correctamente los días feriados).

```
CREATE TABLE Calendario(
    Fecha   date CONSTRAINT PK_Calendario PRIMARY KEY,
    EsFeriado   bit,
    EsFinDeSemana   bit,
    --Cualquier cantidad de columnas que requieras para cálculos de fechas
);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_DiasHabiles ON Calendario(Fecha) WHERE EsFeriado = 0 AND EsFinDeSemana = 0;

WITH 
    E(n) AS(
        SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
    ),
    E2(n) AS(
        SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
    ),
    E4(n) AS(
        SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
    ),
    cteCalendario(Fecha) AS(
        SELECT  DATEADD( DD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, '2000') Fecha
        FROM E4
    )
INSERT INTO Calendario
SELECT Fecha,
       CASE WHEN Fecha IN('20190916', '20190501', '20191225', '20190101'/*, etc*/) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       --CASE WHEN Fecha IN(SELECT Fecha FROM Feriados) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF( DD, '19000101', Fecha) % 7 IN (5,6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM cteCalendario c;
```

De esta forma, nuestra función para calcular fechas puede quedar mucho más sencilla puesto que ya podemos filtrar los atributos directamente y se documenta por si misma. Además, puede hacer uso del índice filtrado que incluí en la definición de la tabla para reducir la cantidad de páginas leídas (algo importante cuando la tabla de calendario tiene muchas columnas).

```
CREATE FUNCTION FechaTerminoSinDiasInhabiles(
    @FechaInicio    DATETIME,
    @Dias           INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    WITH 
    cteDiasHabiles(Fecha) AS(
        SELECT TOP(@Dias) 
                Fecha
        FROM Calendario c
        WHERE EsFeriado = 0
        AND EsFinDeSemana = 0
        AND Fecha >= @FechaInicio
        ORDER BY Fecha
    )
    SELECT MAX(Fecha) FechaTermino
    FROM cteDiasHabiles;
```

Comment: hola! He estado viendo tu codigo y lo veo mucho mejor, creo que a eso se referian unos compañeros cuando me dijeron crea una tabla donde estén los días que no son laborables incluyendo feriados solo que no me explicaron lo demas, soy nuevo en esto y en ningun momento se me habia ocurrido eso. Una consulta si yo quiero insertar el resultado de la funcion FechaTerminoSinDiasInhabiles a una tabla, como seria? Eso estoy que intento hacer en estos momento y no me sale. Muchas gracias

Comment: Tal vez está un poco perdido entre todo el código, pero hay una pequeña parte que muestra como llamar la función usando la cláusula `APPLY`.

Comment: ok, ya salio. Gracias! ^^

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos formas de resolverlo: una manera clásica "iterativa" con un ciclo `while`, dónde básicamente iteras hasta conseguir los 10 días hábiles, con cada ciclo vas incrementando el día desde tu fecha de inicio, y verificas que esta fecha sea un "feriado", si lo es, no lo consideras para la suma de los días. Esta forma puede que no sea óptima a nivel de performance por la repetición de las consultas que hacemos sobre la tabla de `Feriados`, cuanto más grande sea la cantidad de días, seguramente la performance vaya degradándose.

```
DECLARE @I      int
DECLARE @DiasA  int

SELECT  @I     = 0
SELECT  @DiasA = 0

WHILE @DiasA < @Dias
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Feriados WHERE Fecha = DATEADD(DAY, @I, @FechaInicio))
    BEGIN
        SELECT @DiasA = @DiasA + 1
    END
    SELECT  @I = @I + 1
END

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, @I-1, @FechaInicio) as Fecha

Fecha
-----------------------
2019-09-19 00:00:00.000
```

La otra forma, que eventualmente puede ser más óptima, pero, que en realidad es conceptualmente similar a la anterior, es generar dinámicamente una tabla con una cantidad de fechas importante desde tu fecha de inicio, y hacer un `join` con tu tabla de feriados, luego simplemente puedes quitar aquellos días que sean feriados y ver dónde estaría tu fecha límite. Está forma se puede implementar (sql server 2008 o sup.) de la siguiente forma:

```
DECLARE @FechaInicio    DATETIME
DECLARE @Dias       INT

SELECT @FechaInicio = '20190907'
SELECT @Dias        = 10

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 1 AS N UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10
)
SELECT  F1.Fecha
    FROM (SELECT    T.Fecha,
            CASE WHEN F.IdFeriado IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsFeriado,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ISNULL(IdFeriado, -1))  AS Dias
            FROM (SELECT    DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T1.N) - 1, @FechaInicio)  AS Fecha
                    FROM CTE AS T1
                    CROSS JOIN CTE AS T2
            ) T
            LEFT JOIN Feriados F
                on F.Fecha = T.Fecha
    ) F1
    WHERE F1.IsFeriado = 0
        AND F1.Dias = @Dias


Fecha
-----------------------
2019-09-19 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Detalle:

- Usamos un "common table expresion" con un tabla de 10 elementos: `SELECT 1 AS N UNION SELECT 2 UNION ...`, para luego hacer un `cross join` sobre si misma y así generar una consulta con 10 x 10 = 100 filas, este número debe ser superior a tu máximo de días límite.
- Con la tabla anterior, simplemente don `dateadd()` generamos las fechas desde `@FechaInicio` adicionando de a un día por fila gracias al uso de `ROW_NUMBER()`
- Por último `join` con `Feriados` para saber que fecha de todas son feriados y luego simplemente no quedamos con aquella fecha que cumpla con la cantidad de días límite.

Comment: ok amigo, voy a estar probandolo a ver como me va con ambas formas

Comment: Patricio.. esto no es mucho mas simple? o yo entendi mal lo que pide (que igual esta complicado). No alcanza con un not in?

Comment: @gbianchi, lo que se está pidiendo (al menos lo que entendí) es calcular cual es la fecha resultado de sumar 10 días hábiles. El tema es que se piden 10 días hábiles desde un inicio, y si tenes 2 feriados en el medio, vas a decir, tengo que sumar dos días más, pero, el problema es si alguno de esos 2 días es también un feriado. Por eso planteo iterar hasta llegar a los días hábiles esperados.

Comment: esta perfecto.. es como que a la pregunta le falta un pedazo, pero vale...

Comment: @PatricioMoracho listo lo estuve probando con ambos metodos y me quedo con el segundo, era exactamente lo que pedia, gracias amigo me sirvio bastante!

Comment: @PatricioMoracho hola que tal, disculpa un consulta he estado intentando poner una consulta de mi tabla mensajes donde hay una lista de fechas y dias y he intentado agregarlo al codigo que me ayudo. Pero me sale como resultado una fila cuando deberia salirme todo un listado...podria crar un pregunta para que me ayude? por favor?

Comment: Sin duda, una nueva pregunta es lo mejor. Con gusto la miro.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ok, en unos momentos lo estare creando. gracias

Comment: @PatricioMoracho listo aqui esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/290333/d%c3%adas-no-laborales-y-feriados-2-sql-server

Comment: Nota: **SIEMPRE** usa `UNION ALL` en vez de `UNION` a menos de que quieras eliminar duplicados. El rendimiento de tus consultas lo agradecerá.