# Excluir fines de semana de consulta de fechas SQL

Tags: sql

tengo un problema, necesito obtener los dias de diferencia desde la fecha actual a ciertos dias configurados. Pongo en ejemplo mejor:

Hoy 30 de diciembre se realiza el registro de un pago, al seleccionar fecha de pago, solo se pueden seleccionar fecha 4 dias habiles despues de la fecha de registro (4 dias habiles despues de el 30 de diciembre) de lunes a viernes, (no importan los dias feriados, solo que sea de lunes a viernes),
en este escenario que comento, 4 dias habiles desde hoy 30 de diciembre seria el dia 4 de enero, pero como puedo mediante una consulta obtener los dias de diferencia en total (4 de enero - 30 de diciembre son 5 dias de diferencia en total)
como puedo mediante consulta obtener esos 5 dias?

Este ha sido mi intento

```
DECLARE @date1 datetime2 = getdate();
DECLARE @date2 datetime2 = '2021-01-04'
SELECT 
   
    DATEDIFF( day, @date1, @date2 ) AS Days
```

De esta manera tengo los datos manuales en date2, pero sin validar si hubo algun sabado o domingo, como puedo a la fecha actual agregarle los 4 dias configurables omitiendo sabado y domingo, para que el resultado sea el dia 4?

Comment: Échale un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/289891/d%c3%adas-no-laborales-y-feriados)

Answer (score 0):

En tu base de datos crea la siguiente funcion, con este código exacto:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TOTAL_WEEKDAYS(date1 DATE, date2 DATE)
RETURNS INT
RETURN ABS(DATEDIFF(date2, date1)) + 1
     - ABS(DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(date2, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date2) DAY),
                    ADDDATE(date1, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date1) DAY))) / 7 * 2
     - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(date1 < date2, date1, date2)) = 1)
     - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(date1 > date2, date1, date2)) = 7);
```

Para contar los días sin fines de semanas mandas a llamar la siguiente funcion:

```
SELECT TOTAL_WEEKDAYS('2013-08-03', '2013-08-21') diasTrabajados;
```

Esto te dará un número entero de días sin contar fines de semana